# switch between tabs without reloading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im kinda still new to JQ/JS functions, and trying something by myself...so my issue here is that, for example: click on tab named "Tab1" and then an image gets opened. After that if i click again on that very same tab, image slides back, which is fine. But i want that since tab "Tab1" is already opened with image loaded under it, i switch immediately on "Tab2" and when i do that i get image loaded under "Tab2" content without sliding back up or anything, just to look like i first time clicked on that Tab, with all "animations" of smooth slow scroll to the bottom.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5mwc6/) 
example of jq function inside jsfiddle.(1 out of 3)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#inside1').click(function() {
    $("#panel").css('background-image', 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1f/Nsr-slika-015.png)');
  });
});
```

ps: from some reason jsfiddle wont load it as i want, but you still can see the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $panel = $("#panel");
    var $tabs = $('.tab').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            isActive = $this.hasClass('active');
        if ($panel.is(':visible') && !isActive) {
            $panel.css('background-image', 'url(' + $this.data('background') + ')');
            $tabs.removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
        } else {
            if (!isActive) {
                $panel.css('background-image', 'url(' + $this.data('background') + ')');
            }
            $panel.slideToggle();
            $this.toggleClass('active');
        }
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZrBB3/)

Comment: Yes this is perfect! also i would like to ask, how it would look like that every time i click on the tab (Tab1,Tab2 or Tab3) image gets loaded like its first time, with slow sliding on bottom of the div/container?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$(".tab").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = id.substr(id.length - 1, 1);
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {        
        $("#panel").slideUp();
    } else {
        $(".tab.open").removeClass("open");
        if ($("#panel").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#panel").slideDown();            
        }
        $("#panel").removeAttr("class");
            $("#panel").addClass("panel" + id);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/5mwc6/2/)

Comment: Nice Hiral, Thanks. Also i have same question for you like for Arun :)